# How to avoid automatically repeating files in SSIS foreach loop if files come from FTP server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have FTP server where people put some txt files that I need to process. I have for each loop for FTP task and with that, i receive a file to local directory from FTP server. Next, I need to process files from the directory in the foreach loop, and my question is can I somehow protect my loop to don't iterate through the files from past.
Example: someone put files on FTP yesterday. I process them and they are in my local directory. Today someone put a file on FTP, FTP task download them to the local directory and my loop will iterate through all files, yesterday and today. How can I avoid this, without deleting them manually

Comment: 1) Make a staging directory, 2) Add file system task to (copy) *archive files from the staging folder to an archive folder* 3) Add file system task to copy *new* files from FTP to staging. Now you have an archive/history of the files that were processed. Any old files are moved from the directory when the process runs so none are duplicated. New files are copied to the staging folder and processed.

Comment: i will try this, looking fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Hope it works well for you. I have had success in the past with very similar processes.

Comment: @JacobH Why post such a complete answer as a comment?